# My quartz do not execute

Tags: java

My code

```
<bean id="EventNotificationDao" class="cn.secure.dao.EventNotificationDao">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="EventNotificationService" class="cn.secure.service.impl.EventNotificationServiceImpl">
    <property name="EventNotificationDao" ref="EventNotificationDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="myTask" class="cn.secure.web.front.EventNotificationController">
    <property name="EventNotificationService" ref="EventNotificationService" />
</bean>



<bean id="upgradeJobDetail1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref ="myTask" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="addHttpNowData" />

</bean>
    <bean id="upgradeTrigger1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="upgradeJobDetail1" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/2 * * ? * *"/>
</bean>
```

The configuration is not executed and no error is reported

```
<bean   lazy-init="false"
  class=" org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">   
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>  
        <ref bean="upgradeTrigger1"  />

        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="executor" />

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<bean lazy-init=‘false’ class=" org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">   
<property name="triggers">
    <list>  
        <ref bean="upgradeTrigger1"  />
    </list>
</property>
<property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
<property name="startupDelay" value="30"/>
</bean>
```